# Passport authentication not working in sails.js application

Tags: node.js, authentication, sails.js, passport.js, passport-local

I have a Sails JS application. I am trying to setup authentication using Passport.js authentication layer [sails-generate-auth](https://github.com/kasperisager/sails-generate-auth). I have configured my app by following the steps given in their documentation.

But when I lift my sails app, authentication is not working. I am able to access the controllers, even when I am not logged in (It's not redirecting to my login page).

I added a `console.log` statement in `api/policies/passport.js` as follows:

```
module.exports = function (req, res, next) {
  passport.initialize()(req, res, function () {
    passport.session()(req, res, function () {
      res.locals.user = req.user;
      console.log(req.user); // added by me
      next(); 
    });
  });
};
```

Now, when I access controllers before login or after logout, its printing `undefined`. But when I am logged in, its printing my user data. Any idea why it is not checking for authentication?

I am using local authentication strategy and I have commented out all others (twitter, facebook...)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Passport doesn't have a policy to deny access to a controller. For this, you have to create another policy.

See this [link](https://github.com/kasperisager/sails-generate-auth/issues/112) for more details.

Answer (score 12):

The above answer provides useful information. I want to elaborare on that.

sails-generate-auth, by default doesn't deny access to controllers if the user is not logged in. For that, you can create another policy in `api/policies/`. For example: create `sessionAuth` policy as follows:

```
module.exports = function(req, res, next) {
  if (req.user) {
    return next();
  }

  return res.forbidden('You are not permitted to perform this action.');
};
```

Instead of showing forbidden page, you can also render login page. For that you need access to AuthController.login. So, add the policies in `config/policies` as follows:

```
'*': ['passport', 'sessionAuth'],

'auth': {
  '*': ['passport']
}
```

This helps to restrict access all the controllers except auth controllers such as login, logout and register, if the user is not logged in.

Comment: I've made the above alterations to config/policies.  I am now getting a 401 error for my controllers (for example, GET /user) even AFTER a successful login (via Postman packaged app, which seems to be keeping the relevant cookies).  When I run the node debugger, on the sessionAuth policy, I find that req.session exists (with the ID of the current user) but req.session.authenticated was never set, so the authentication fails.

Comment: If you are using sails-generate-auth, currently the module doesn't have support for API authentication. I've given a pull request to add that. But you can use this [even-more-passport](https://github.com/sails101/even-more-passport) to know how to integrate API authentication. If you have any questions, raise an issue there. It is maintained by me and I'll surely help you.