# Securing a page with using passport.js, sails.js and sails generate auth

Tags: javascript, node.js, sails.js, passport.js, sails-generate-auth

How do I secure a page so I cannot be accessed by a non authenticated user? I've read the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27168229/passport-authentication-not-working-in-sails-js-application) but I haven't been able to correctly secure a page with sails generate auth for sails.js, using passport.js.

Thanks.

Comment: Start with the Passportjs documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you generated your application, a `sessionAuth` policy [must have been created](http://sailsjs.org/documentation/anatomy/my-app/api/policies/session-auth-js). This is an example policy that is created when you generate a sails app. It is not part of `sails-generate-auth`.

To use it for your secured routes, write your configuration in the [config/policies.js](http://sailsjs.org/documentation/anatomy/my-app/config/policies-js) file.

```
SecuredController: {
    // Apply the `sessionAuth` policy for all of SecuredController's actions
    '*': 'sessionAuth',
};
```

[`sails-generate-auth` will populate `req.session.authenticated`](https://github.com/kasperisager/sails-generate-auth/blob/master/templates/api/controllers/AuthController.js#L168-L169) during the login so the `sessionAuth` policy will behave as expected if you correctly configured your `config/policies.js` file.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. In addition, I must indicate is not possible to set a policy to a view, must be a controller. If is necessary to secure a view, you can return it from a controller, like this: res.view({ 'myView': {} });